# Scanning an Array for String Matches in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays

I have an array that looks like this:

```
foo = ["25\"/64cm", "0\"/0cm", "0\"/0cm", "0\"/0cm", "2\"/6cm", "0\"/0cm", "0\"/0cm", "0\"/0cm", "0\"/0cm", "0\"/0cm"]
```

I am trying to scan the array, and return a new array of the values (integers) between the / and cm. I am hoping it would come out at:

```
bar = [64, 0, 0, 0, 6, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

Sorry I am new to ruby

Comment: Hope you are not sorry for stepping into Ruby.

Comment: Not at all! Loving the journey

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There should be at least one answer that doesn't use a regex:

```
foo.map { |s| s.split('/').last.to_i }
  #=> [64, 0, 0, 0, 6, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

Comment: works great. What would be the benefit of not using a regex? Thanks

Comment: Here I don't think it matters. The use of a regex, as @Santosh has done, is clear and easy to read. In general, regular expressions can be extremely useful, providing compact ways to easily manipulate text where the use of other methods is cumbersome at best. On the other hand, it is possible to craft regexes that are so complex that testing and (especially) maintenance are a real challenge. I suggest you revisit this question after you've had more experience with Ruby in general and regexes in particular.

Answer (score 2):

```
foo.map {|s| s[/\d+cm/].to_i }
# => [64, 0, 0, 0, 6, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

Comment: Work brilliantly. Cheers!

Comment: @AndrewWalz if you find an answer is working for you, you should  accept it, not only upvote it.

Comment: @RubyRacer, perhaps, but there's no rush to do so. Andrew, give it some time before making a selection.  You don't want to discourage other answers with a quick selection, and you don't want to short-circuit any readers who are still preparing answers. Many OP's wait hours or even a day before making a selection. But yes, a good answer. +1

Comment: @RubyRacer, I had seen that. imo, it makes no difference. For one thing, it's just a courtesy to give others time to post their ansers before a selection is made.  Also, I have often seen a brilliant answer selected, only to be trumped by a killer answer later. Sure, the OP can change the selection later, but that's rarely done, especially by newbies.

Comment: Sorry guys. Cant upvote with below 15 reputation and I couldn't accept it before 7 minutes

Answer (score 1):

```
foo.map { |s| /(\d+)cm/.match(s)[1].to_i }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try This:

```
foo.join().scan(/\b(\d+cm)/).flatten.map{|x| x.to_i}
```